# Cocos2D upgrade - wrong object y coordinate

Tags: object, properties, cocos2d-iphone, coordinates

I've been having a lot of issues upgrading to Cocos2D 2.1, and just taking it one step at a time. I have an issue that I'm trying to figure out that is baffling: An object's y coordinate value from a tmx map is totally wrong.

On the hd tmx file, the object is defined with properties:

```
<object name="SaveStation" type="10006" x="304" y="752" width="96" height="32"/>
```

When initializing my scene, I get the x/y value properties of the SaveStation object listed above:

```
CCTMXObjectGroup *objects = [theMap objectGroupNamed:@"oj"];
NSMutableDictionary *startPoint = [objects objectNamed:@"SaveStation"]; 

int x = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
int y = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];

NSLog(@"x = %i",x);
NSLog(@"y = %i",y);
```

Strangely enough, it logs out:

x = 304

y = 1456

Comment: I noticed in SD mode the y coordinate also logs as something different: 336, while the x remains the same as hd (304). However, the SD displays the object's position correctly.

Comment: Upon further examination, it SHOULD be grabbing 336 as the retina y value, but for some reason it gives me 1456.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out...

CCTMXXMLParser.m is referencing the tile height value from the HD map in literal pixels instead of points!

[code]// Y
        value = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"y"];
        if( value )  {
        int y = [value intValue] + objectGroup.positionOffset.y;

```
        // Correct y position. (Tiled uses Flipped, cocos2d uses Standard)
        y = (_mapSize.height * _tileSize.height) - y - [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"height"] intValue];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y] forKey:@"y"];
    }[/code]
```

_tileSize.height will return 32. So I need to have it use a tile size of 16 instead of 32.